# How to determine if client expects a JSON response

Tags: python, http, http-headers, mime-types

In my Werkzeug application I am intercepting all error responses and trying to respond with a JSON response if the client expects JSON or return the usual HTML page with 404 or 500:

```
def handle_error_response(self, environ, start_response, exc):
    if ('application/json' in environ.get('CONTENT_TYPE', '')
            and exc.get_response().content_type != 'application/json'):
        start_response('%s %s' % (exc.code, exc.name),
                       (('Content-Type', 'application/json'), ))
        return (json.dumps({"success": False, "error": exc.description}, ensure_ascii=False), )
    # go the regular path
    ...
```

In this solution I am relying on `Content-Type` header containing string`'application/json'`.

However this doesn't look like a correct solution, because Wikipedia says:

> **Content-Type** The MIME type of the body of the request (used with POST and PUT requests)

Is it a good strategy to check if `'text/html'` is inside header `Accept` and then return HTML response otherwise return JSON response?

Any other more robust solutions?

When Chrome requests an HTML page header

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

is sent, when Ember makes an API request

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

is sent.

Maybe `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` should be taken into account?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add [AcceptMixin](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.AcceptMixin) to your request object.

Once you do this, you can use the `accept_mimetypes.accept_json`, `accept_mimetypes.accept_html` and `accept_mimetypes.accept_xhtml` attributes on your request object. The response's default content type really depends only on what your application is; just try and imagine which would result in less confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `AcceptMixin`, but my question is how to use information `AcceptMixin.accept_mimetypes` provides. When Chrome requests HTML page `'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'` is sent, when Ember makes an API request `'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'` is sent. And in both cases `request.accept_mimetypes.accept_json` == `request.accept_mimetypes.accept_html` == `True`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for us:

```
    if ('text/html' not in environ.get('HTTP_ACCEPT', '')
            and 'application/json' not in response.content_type):
        # the user agent didn't explicitely request html, so we return json
        ...  # make the JSON response
```

I.e. if the client expects html -- do not return json. Otherwise return
json response, if the response isn't already json.